# adjust Learning Rate in a deep neural network

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

Currently I am training a YOLO model to detect object, but I have noted that sometimes the loss in the output is like in a loop, for example "in 20 minute of training my loss was between 0.2 and 0.5 each time that my program decrease to 0.2 it's automatically increase to 0.5 and it loop like that "

My question is: Do I need to change my learning rate if the loss loop?

Answer (score 0):

Learning rate is a possibility (not the only one). Optimizing the learning rate (and also scheduling the decay if needed) might be the most important thing in training procedure.

You need to have a good sense about the loss value (roughly what do you expect to get and what is the value of loss in the beginning of training).
Also, since YOLO is an object detection algorithm (I don't remember the details of paper completely), is classification or regression or both losses are high.

Also take a look at your data. You may need to shuffle your data before using it in your training.

It's a late answer but if you give me feedback about what I've mentioned I might be able to help more.